# Showing 3 tables Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

1. image of my database table
   [3 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjS9M.png)
2. this is the layout from my web.data in table 'pembayaran_infaq' is only 1 row but this is duplicate
   [duploicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIfq.png)
3. data from table 'pembayaran_spp' and 'pembayaran_infaq' in database
   [data from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWxFS.png)

im already try but the data from 'pembayaran_infaq' is duplicate. i want to show 'pembayaran_spp' and 'pembayaran_infaq' using `$id_siswa`. thank you

## my_model

```
function riwayatbayarsiswa($id_siswa)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('siswa a');
        $this->db->join('pembayaran_spp b','b.id_siswa=a.id_siswa','left');
        $this->db->join('pembayaran_infaq c', 'c.id_siswa=a.id_siswa','left');
        $this->db->where('a.id_siswa',$id_siswa);
        //$this->db->distinct();
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

## my controller

```
function riwayatbayar($id_siswa)
    {
        $data['siswa'] = $this->M_keuangan->riwayatbayarsiswa($id_siswa)->result();
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('keuangan/v_detailtagihan',$data);
        //$this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

Comment: @pradeep it doesnt work sir.

Comment: it doesnt work "Undefined property: stdClass::$nama_siswa". it is in my view. the data from the tables is duplicate too.i have 2 row data in table 'pembayaran_spp' and 1 row in table 'pembayaran_infaq'. its show 2 and 2 in the view. its duplicate from 'pembayaran_infaq'

Comment: without seeing your table data unable to help u but  for now try with `inner join` instead of `left join`

Comment: the data from the table is show correctly. 2 row in 'pembayaran_spp'. but the data in table 'pembayaran_infaq' is duplicate show. should i put the view code too?